# Biztalk WCF won't show up custom behavior

Tags: wcf, port, biztalk, windows-server-2016, biztalk-2016

I created a custom behavior for BizTalk in order to connect to an API with Oauth authentication.

I did these steps :

1. I added it to the GAC
2. Added the lines in machine.config (both)
3. restarted IIS, Biztalk admin console

I can even see it with SvcConfigEditor.

However when I create a WCF-Custom and try to add the Behavior, it is actually nowhere in the pick list. 
Any idea please?

Answer (score 0):

So....yes, it does work, but WCF being...well...WCF...

You do have to restart the machine.  I don't recall ever getting this to work without doing so.

Then just keep checking the registration against other examples.  Eventually, you'll get it.

Comment: Actually the reason was the name of the assembly, when I changed it to something like adapter.biztalk.behavior (or something like that) it worked. (Sorry I took so long to answer, I forgot to come back here).

Answer (score 0):

Import your behaviour extension in Adapter Handler level.

In your biztalk administration console, go to Adapters -> Select the adapter and click the Handler Properties and import your extension.

[image]
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it will add it to all ports that use this adater.